# RabbitMQ consumer that gets data from more than one exchange

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm building a basic event based message system for a couple of services.

For my user service, I'm going to use a `user` topic exchange which will have routing keys like `user.event.created`, `user.event.updated` and `user.event.deleted`.

My logs service will consume `user.event.*` keys so I can log all events, whereas my email service will only listen for `user.event.created` as I'll only send out email on creation.

Now say I created a posts service, I want the logs service to consume events from here as well. Is it ok for me to bind both exchanges to the single `logs.process` queue?

Is there a better way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as each of the consume threads has it's own connection, it's fine. So, one thread consumes from topic exchange, the other from direct one etc.

As for the better part, I don't know - would require some more details.